# What's is called when you think something is better because it's newer/more recent?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology

I really feel like there's a word or phrase for this, but I honestly can't think of it. What's it called when you think something 
is better because it's newer/more recent?

As an example, say an artist has just released a new album. On listening to it, you're absolutely sure this is the best work they've released. You could revisit it at another time when you're more used to it or something and think differently, but in that moment, when it's brand new and different, you like it best. What's that feeling called?

Apologies if this isn't necessarily the type of question you folks answer on here. I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of fallacies, claiming something is better because it is newer is an **appeal to novelty**.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_novelty):

> The appeal to novelty (also called argumentum ad novitatem) is a fallacy in which one prematurely claims that an idea or proposal is correct or superior, exclusively because it is new and modern.

[TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AppealToNovelty):

> Appeal to Novelty is a logical fallacy where someone claims that a proposal, idea, work, or trend is better or more accurate than what came before, solely because it is newer or more recent.
>
> This argument is often made with regard to technology, where it is often supposed that anything "high tech" is automatically better than anything "low tech."

[Logicaly Fallacious](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/38/Appeal-to-Novelty):

> Claiming that something that is new or modern is superior to the status quo, based exclusively on its newness.

The equivalent way of thinking can be called a **novelty bias**, since biases are commonly named by what they favor. [The Catalogue of Bias](https://catalogofbias.org/biases/novelty-bias/) describes the *novelty bias* in a medical research context:

> Novelty bias refers to the mere appearance that a new treatment is better when it is new

Answer (score 0):

A person having such characteristics would be considered a "**neophile**". Apparently there is a condition which itself is referred to as "**neophilia**".

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Neophile

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/neophilia